# PHP ramdom word without repeat

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
$banner1 = 'text 1';
$banner2 = 'text 2';
$banner3 = 'text 3';
$banner4 = 'text 4';
$banner5 = 'text 5';
$banner6 = 'text 6';
$banner7 = 'text 7';
$banner8 = 'text 8';
$banner9 = 'text 9';
$banners = array($banner1, $banner2, $banner3, $banner4, $banner5, $banner6, $banner7, $banner8, $banner9);
shuffle($banners);
?>

<?php print $banners[0] ?>
```

how i can make to the values (text 1,2,3...) does not recur?

PS: not repeat to the same user, on reload the page (F5)

(Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: You can use `looping statement` ....!!

Comment: This code should print only 1 element, so whats the question of recurrence?

Comment: not repeat on reload the page (F5)

Comment: shuffle($banners); is already work like loop

Comment: you can use time for your random genration

Comment: with the user reloading, you would have to store (somewhere(db,session.cookie)) what that particular user had seen before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is... Save it in session, remove from array after printing it. Save it again in session.

```
session_start();
$banner1 = 'text 1';
$banner2 = 'text 2';
$banner3 = 'text 3';
$banner4 = 'text 4';
$banner5 = 'text 5';
$banner6 = 'text 6';
$banner7 = 'text 7';
$banner8 = 'text 8';
$banner9 = 'text 9';
$banners = isset($_SESSION['banners']) ? $_SESSION['banners'] : array($banner1, $banner2, $banner3, $banner4, $banner5, $banner6, $banner7, $banner8, $banner9);
shuffle($banners);

echo $banners[0];
unset($banners[0]);
$_SESSION['banners'] = $banners;

if( count($_SESSION['banners']) == 0 ) unset($_SESSION['banners']);
```

Comment: is possible do a random from "1 to 9" without repeating? repeating only after all the numbers from 1 to 9 to appear?

Comment: Yes. I updated my answer. `if( count($_SESSION['banners']) == 0 ) unset($_SESSION['banners']);`

Comment: Thank you very much! Thank you, solved my problem, I love you haha